# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Purchases on migration to Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, carthage

I am in the process of migration from a carthage based project to SPM. I have moved over all my dependencies (except a few that are still in cocoapods), and can get the project to compile, but have found that when I run, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Purchases.framework/Purchases
```

I don't this is specifically a problem with the framework as I have been able to get a test project to work correctly, but am wondering if there could be a compiler setting or a remnant from my usage of carthage that is causing problems. I have cleaned and removed DerivedData. I can still see and import legacy frameworks into XCode that I built and used via carthage that are no longer part of the project, which might explain the problem. So far searching for this has not resulted in any success solving the problem, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Inexplicably (at least to me) the problem appears to be that I still had the Carthage folder in the root of my project folder. If I moved that out, things worked as they should. If I moved it back, I get the linking error. If this is  a compiler setting or if someone has more info, please post and I will mark yours as the more useful answer.